# Understanding kinematics formula in two dimensions

Tags: physics

Determine the angle of projection of a projectile if its speed at maximum height is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}$ of its speed at half the maximum height.

My solution:

$$H_{max}=\frac{{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)}{2g}\implies \frac{1}{2}H_{max}=\frac{{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)}{4g}\\v_{x}=v_0\cos(\theta)\quad {v_{\frac{H}{2}y}}^2={v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)-2g\left(\frac{{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)}{4g}\right)=\frac{1}{2}{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)\\v_0\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\sqrt{{v_0}^2\cos^2(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)}\\\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos^2(\theta)}\\\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{5}\cos^2(\theta)+\frac{1}{5}\\\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{4}\implies\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\implies\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$$
Solution found on another website:
$$gH_{max}=\frac{{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)}{2}\quad {v_x}^2={v_0}^2\cos^2(\theta)\\{v_{\frac{H}{2}}}^2={v_0}^2-2g\left(\frac{1}{2}H_{max}\right)={v_0}^2-\frac{{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)}{2}\\v_{0}\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}v_{\frac{H}{2}}\implies {v_{0}}^2\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{2}{5}{v_{\frac{H}{2}}}^2=\frac{2}{5}\left({v_0}^2-\frac{{v_0}^2\sin^2(\theta)}{2}\right)\\5\cos^2(\theta)=2-\sin^2(\theta)=1+\cos^2(\theta)\\\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{4}\implies\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\implies\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

What I don't quite understand in the second solution is the application of the kinematics formula $v^2={v_0}^2+2a\Delta d$ (second line). I thought the formula held only for one dimensional kinematics, but its usage here would imply two dimensional vector addition since the initial velocity and gravity aren't parallel vectors. Can someone help clarify this for me?

Comment: Sorry, I actually made a mistake, I actually meant $v^2$. I edited it btw

Comment: However I'm still not quite understanding the 2d application of the formula

Comment: Link me to the website please

Comment: https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-physics/mechanics/motion-of-projectile.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You know that

$$v_y^2 = v_{0y}^2 + 2a_y\Delta y$$ and that
$$v_x^2 = v_{0x}^2 + 2a_x\Delta x.$$

First,

$$v^2 = \textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{v} = \left(v_x \hat{\textbf{x}} + v_y \hat{\textbf{y}}\right)\cdot\left(v_x \hat{\textbf{x}} + v_y \hat{\textbf{y}}\right) = v_x^2 + v_y^2.$$

Second,

$$v_0^2 = \textbf{v}_0\cdot\textbf{v}_0 = v_{0x}^2 + v_{0y}^2,$$

and

$$2a_x\Delta x = 0.$$

Last, $$v^2 = v_0^2 - 2g\Delta y.$$

Comment: By the way, despite being a fourth-year physics major, I didn't know this until now. I just figured it out. I learned something thanks to your question.

Comment: If you don't know dot products, you can probably still follow this if you ignore them.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of an explanation?

Comment: You don't understand why $v^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2$ is what you mean?

Comment: If so, then think of it geometrically: $v_x$ and $v_y$ are two legs of a right triangle and $v$ is the hypotenuse---Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Oh wait got it. Thanks